# What is the difference in my code as compared to the code I found on Google to check if my code is right?

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

in short, the question is, I want to delete the last element of the DOUBLY LINKED LIST and I wrote this function...

```
fun deleteLast(){
    if(isEmpty()){println("list is empty")}
    if (head!=null && head?.nextNode == null){
        head = null
    }else {
        tail = tail?.previousNode
        tail?.nextNode = null
    }
}
```

I went to the tail without traversing it and made its previous as new tail and new tail next(old tail) as null. And my result is desirable.
after writing this I pinged Google to check if this is right so, I found this...

```
void pop_back() {
if(this.head != null) {
//1. if head in not null and next of head
//   is null, release the head
if(this.head.next == null) {
  this.head = null;
} else {
  
  //2. Else, traverse to the second last 
  //   element of the list
  Node temp = new Node();
  temp = this.head;
  while(temp.next.next != null)
    temp = temp.next;
  
  //3. Change the next of the second 
  //   last node to null and delete the
  //   last node
  Node lastNode = temp.next;
  temp.next = null; 
  lastNode = null;
  }
 }
}
```

I want to ask If my code is right I just want you masters to review it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to judge this without seeing the rest of your code.  (I tried guessing it, but got confused as to how you can have `head`, `tail`, `previousNode` _and_ `nextNode`…)

Comment: It's Doubly Linked List sir & I declare previous, next & node value in node class constructors & head & tail in Doubly Linkedlist class body as a type Node.

Answer (score 0):

The question only contains a snippet, not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so for the sake of argument (based on existing code and the comment) I'm going to assume that the full code looks something like this:

```
class Node<T>(var previousNode: Node<T>?, var nextNode: Node<T>?, var value: T)

class DoublyLinkedList<T>(var head: Node<T>?, var tail: Node<T>?) {
    fun isEmpty() = head == null

    // …other methods…

    fun deleteLast(){
        if(isEmpty()){println("list is empty")}
        if (head!=null && head?.nextNode == null){
            head = null
        }else {
            tail = tail?.previousNode
            tail?.nextNode = null
        }
    }
}
```

Given this, it looks like your code is about right.  There are a few points that could be addressed<sup>*</sup>, e.g.:

- Inside the second `if` I think it needs to set `tail` to null as well, for safety.
- Inside the second and third branches, you might want to set to null the `previousNode` and `nextNode` references in the node you're removing, for the benefit of any other code that still has a reference to it.  (That might also give an extra hint to the garbage collector, though that shouldn't be needed.)
- Instead of calling `isEmpty()`, it'd be simpler and more consistent to check whether `head` is null.
- I'd add an `else` before the second `if`.  As it is, the code works for an empty list, but that may be just luck; it'd be much more robust if neither of the other branches could be called on an empty list.  (In some cases, this could let the compiler smart-cast `head` to non-nullable; but that doesn't happen here because it's mutable.)
- In production code, you wouldn't print to stdout like that.  If it's allowed to call `deleteLast()` on an empty list, then there's no need to print anything; if not (which would be more usual), you'd throw an exception.  (And the method would have a doc comment explaining that.)
- The formatting could be improved.

<sup>(* In my experience, *any* code can be improved — even code you've worked on many times before!)</sup>

However, **you can't compare your code directly to the Google-sourced code, because it looks like that is for a *singly*-linked list.**

A singly-linked list is a much simpler structure.  All it has is a reference to the `head` node; that has a reference to the `next` node (and, presumably to the data stored in the node); and so on.  So the *only* way to reach the end of the list is to traverse all the nodes, as the Google-sourced code does.  (This also means there's often no point in having a separate class to represent the list as a whole; a reference to the first node is all you need.  Many operations can be written concisely with recursive methods.  You can also make it immutable, which has many advantages; that's the primary data structure in some languages.)

Your list, though, has a direct reference to the last node, which of course avoids the need to traverse the entire list to find it.  As your code demonstrates, this means that some operations are much more efficient in double-linked lists.  There are corresponding disadvantages, though: each node takes more memory; there are more references to update when changing the list; it's easier for the list to get into an inconsistent state; and it's less suitable for an immutable list.)

Comment: You solved my problem, sir! Thank you so much!